# Unable to make Istio HTTPS gateway working?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-elb, istio

I installed Istio 1.4.3 on K8S 1.15.9 with below command.

```
istioctl manifest apply --set profile=demo --set values.grafana.enabled=false --set values.prometheus.enabled=false --set values.global.mtls.enabled=true --set values.global.controlPlaneSecurityEnabled=true
```

Above command created AWS classic LB with listener on port 443 with LB and instance protocol as TCP - `443 (SSL, ACM Certificate: 7869fda2-blah-4eee-7f3d-e8c6310464de) forwarding to 31421 (TCP)`

Where above certificate is for `*.domain.com`.

Then, I deployed `grafana` in `debug` namespace and created below to access it.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway 
metadata: 
  name: grafana-gateway 
  namespace: debug 
spec: 
  selector: 
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway 
  servers:
  - port: 
      number: 443 
      name: https 
      protocol: HTTPS 
    tls: 
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL 
    hosts:
    - '*.domain.com'
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3 
kind: VirtualService 
metadata: 
  name: grafana 
  namespace: debug 
spec: 
  hosts:
  - grafana.domain.com 
  gateways:
  - grafana-gateway 
  http:
  - route:
    - destination: 
        host: grafana.debug.svc.cluster.local
        port: 
          number: 3000
```

Now, I want to access grafana with URL https://grafana.domain.com. Which I'm not able to do. :-(

With `curl` I'm getting `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers,

-ajit

Comment: try to declare the DestinationRule too

Comment: @c4f4t0r 
Can you please elaborate more on why it's needed? And if it's what/how it should be.

Comment: How did you try to connect to the service, could you show the complete curl command, thanks :)

Comment: BTW,

`apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway 
metadata: 
  name: grafana-gateway 
  namespace: debug 
spec: 
  selector: 
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway 
  servers:
  - port: 
      number: 443 
      name: https 
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - '*.domain.com'`
If I change my gateway to above, it's working. I'm confused. Why is HTTP working and not HTTPS?

Comment: What if You add destination rule like [here](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/gateways/), which disable tls, it works then? Can you use `curl -v` and let me know what errors you get from there with, and without destination rule? I assume since you disabled grafana in your command it's your own grafana, not the addon built in demo profile?